Issue with API Connection in Power Query
Thanks for any help anyone can give here.
I'm trying to connect PowerBI to a system via Rest API. The initial connection is working and a token is bein returned, which is "apiToken" and I'm passing it in the Authorization line here. But no matter what I try, it is giving me "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again" or "Please specify how to connect" errors.
I've replaced the URL with URLURLURL and the API key with APIKEYAPIKEY
  response = Web.Contents(url, [Headers = [#"Authorization" = "apiToken",#"x-api-key" = "ba71cb2f-dede-47b5-940a-198c7477238a",#"Content-Type" = "application/json"],

If I replace apiToken with the actual token, the connection works. I've tried any version of the "apiToken" that I can think might work, including researched options. Nothing works.

Power BI's M language doesn’t handle dynamic variable substitution in headers as expected, so when "apiToken" is used directly within the header, Power BI treats it as a literal string rather than the variable's value.
You can try to define the token as a variable and then reference it within the headers:
let
    url = "URLURLURL",
    apiToken = "YOUR_ACTUAL_API_TOKEN_VALUE", // Replace with the actual token variable returned by the initial request
    response = Web.Contents(url, 
        [
            Headers = [
                #"Authorization" = "Bearer " & apiToken,
                #"x-api-key" = "ba71cb2f-dede-47b5-940a-198c7477238a",
                #"Content-Type" = "application/json"
            ]
        ]
    )
in
    response

